# Combine all the similar lists in a list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list of lists having the following pattern :

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$Jobs
 [1] "Principal Data Scientist"              "Principal Data Scientist"             
 [3] "Principal Data Scientist"              "Principal Data Scientist"                                           
 [5] "Data Science Analyst"                  "Data Science Analyst"                 

[[1]]$Company
 [1] "IBM"                           "Lightpath"                     "Huawei Technologies"          
 [4] "Dealertrack"                   "J.P. Morgan"                   "Noviya Systems"                                              

[[2]]
[[2]]$Jobs
 [1] "Data Science Analyst"                     "Data Science Analyst"                    
 [3] "Data Science Analyst"                     "Data Science Analyst"                                     
 [5] "Data Science Engineer"                    "Data Science Engineer"                   

[[2]]$Company
 [1] "Petro IT"                 "Analytic Partners"        "Affinity Health Plan"    
 [4] "IBM"                      "Commvault"                "J. Crew"                         

[[3]]
[[3]]$Jobs
 [1] "Data Science Manager"                       "Data Science Manager"                      
 [3] "Data Science Manager"                       "Data Science Manager"                                          
 [5] "Staff Data Scientist"                       "Staff Data Scientist"                      

[[3]]$Company
 [1] "ASDA group"               "RTW Retailwinds"          "BASF"                    
 [4] "Futures Action Network"   "RCI Exchanges"            "Sizmek"
```

Now, I want an output where all the similar lists are grouped into one like the following:

```
$Jobs
 [1] "Principal Data Scientist"              "Principal Data Scientist"             
 [3] "Principal Data Scientist"              "Principal Data Scientist"                                           
 [5] "Data Science Analyst"                  "Data Science Analyst"    
 [7] "Data Science Analyst"                  "Data Science Analyst"                    
 [9] "Data Science Analyst"                  "Data Science Analyst"                                     
[11] "Data Science Engineer"                 "Data Science Engineer"                   
[13] "Data Science Manager"                  "Data Science Manager"                      
[15] "Data Science Manager"                  "Data Science Manager"                                          
[17] "Staff Data Scientist"                  "Staff Data Scientist"

$Company
 [1] "IBM"                           "Lightpath"                     "Huawei Technologies"          
 [4] "Dealertrack"                   "J.P. Morgan"                   "Noviya Systems" 
 [7] "Petro IT"                      "Analytic Partners"             "Affinity Health Plan"    
[10] "IBM"                           "Commvault"                     "J. Crew"
[13] "ASDA group"                    "RTW Retailwinds"               "BASF"                    
[16] "Futures Action Network"        "RCI Exchanges"                 "Sizmek"
```

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is a nested list.  So, we loop over the `list`, `stack` to a two column data.frame, `rbind` the `list` elements and `split` based on the 'ind' column

```
d1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, function(x) stack(x)))
with(d1, split(values, ind))
```

---

Or another option is to flatten the `list` and `split`

```
lst2 <- do.call(c, lst1)
split(unlist(lst2, use.names = FALSE),  rep(names(lst2), lengths(lst2)))
```

---

Or can also `unlist` directly and then `split` by the substring of the `names` of the `unlist`ed vector

```
split(unlist(lst1, use.names = FALSE), sub("\\d+$", "", names(unlist(lst1))))
```

---

Or can `transpose` and `unlist`

```
library(purrr)
transpose(lst1) %>% 
       map(unlist)
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(list(Jobs = c("Principal Data Scientist", "Principal Data Scientist", 
"Data Science Analyst"), Company = c("IBM", "Lightpath")), list(
    Jobs = c("Principal Data Scientist", "Principal Data Scientist", 
    "Data Science Analyst"), Company = c("IBM", "Lightpath")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `mapply` with `do.call` could help (thank @akrun's data)

```
> do.call(function(...) mapply(c, ...), lst)
$Jobs
[1] "Principal Data Scientist" "Principal Data Scientist"
[3] "Data Science Analyst"     "Principal Data Scientist"
[5] "Principal Data Scientist" "Data Science Analyst"

$Company
[1] "IBM"       "Lightpath" "IBM"       "Lightpath"
```

---

Or you can use `list2DF` + `apply` + `unlist`

```
> apply(list2DF(lst), 1, unlist)
[[1]]

"Principal Data Scientist" "Principal Data Scientist"

    "Data Science Analyst" "Principal Data Scientist"

"Principal Data Scientist"     "Data Science Analyst"

[[2]]

      "IBM" "Lightpath"       "IBM" "Lightpath"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list `->` L, we can try:

```
Map(c,L[[1]],L[[2]],L[[3]])
```